# image.onload not firing in node.js

Tags: node.js, canvas, onload

I'm attempting to draw an image onto a canvas in Node.js

This is my code currently:

```
var canvas = new Canvas(960, 540);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
img.src = "<image url>";
```

When I ran the program, the `img.onload` event never fired, which caused the canvas to be blank. I have made sure the `img.src` is placed after the `img.onload` as I have seen in other questions, but it is still not working for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you writing is this code directly into node or are you using any framework ? Node does not support anything as such in general

Comment: @PrajvalM I am using the canvas node module if that's what you're asking
I have seen other people using `image.onload` in their node applications and seen some other answers on here using the same thing. If I do not include the event, I get an error saying the image hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: I never used this package, but fast reading the Internets, shouldn't it be `img = new Canvas.Image`?

Comment: @Kaiido looking [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images), you can see that using a HTML canvas (which the canvas module fully recreates) you would use `img = new Image()` rather than `img = new Canvas.Image()`, though I could try it out later when I can

Comment: ... Node by itself has no concept of DOM nor of HTMLElement. The `Image()` constructor in this article is the `window.Image` one, which is a shorthand for `Image = (width, height) => Object.assign(document.createElement('img'), {width, height})` But *node-canvas*  along with an HTMLCanvas shim, does implement a `Canvas.Image` constructor which will shim HTMLImageElement, at least for their Canvas object's use (I guess it's more a shim of ImageBitmap actually). So you need to use this shim.

Comment: @Kaiido Using `img = Canvas.Image` does not fire `img.onload` either. When I don't use `img.onload`, I get an exception saying `Image given has not completed loading`